# How to use Hadoop InputFormats In Apache Spark?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

I have a class `ImageInputFormat` in Hadoop which reads images from HDFS. How to use my InputFormat in Spark?

Here is my `ImageInputFormat`:

```
public class ImageInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<Text, ImageWritable> {

    @Override
    public ImageRecordReader createRecordReader(InputSplit split, 
                  TaskAttemptContext context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new ImageRecordReader();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path filename) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [SparkContext](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/api/core/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) has a method called `hadoopFile`. It accepts classes implementing the interface `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat`

Its description says "Get an RDD for a Hadoop file with an arbitrary InputFormat".

Also have a look at the [Spark Documentation](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/scala-programming-guide.html#hadoop-datasets).

Comment: Thank you~ I figure it out now. Instead, I use newAPIHadoopFile to do the job.But I have a new problem that will these images all be stored in hadoopRDD or I can set the RDD capacity and when the RDD is full, the rest data will be stored in disk? Futhermore will the performance be influenced if the data is too big? There are 500G images of the input. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really a Spark expert. I hope somebody else can answer it.

Answer (score 2):

> images all be stored in hadoopRDD ?

yes, everything that will be saved in spark is as rdds

> can set the RDD capacity and when the RDD is full, the rest data will be stored in disk?

Default storage level in spark is (StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY) ,use MEMORY_ONLY_SER, which is more space efficient. Please refer spark documentation > scala programming > RDD persistance

> Will the performance be influenced if the data is too big?

As data size increases , it will effect performance too.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just a moment ago, i was puzzled about java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. So according to your reply, Storage Level setting may probable be the problem! My cluster has 1 master and 11 slaves. Each of the node has 6G memory.In my program, i set spark.executor.memory to 3g. The data to be processed is about 22g which contains 10000 images. Thank you again:)