# Apache Spark Word Count on PDF file

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, readfile, rdd

I want to read the pdf files in hdfs and do word count. I know [how to do this in Map Reduce](https://amalgjose.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/pdf-input-format-implementation-for-hadoop-mapreduce/).
I need to do the same in Apache Spark. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:
Modify the code in the blog post you referenced to write the PDF words to a HDFS file or event a plain text file.  That post references another one of the author's posts https://amalgjose.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/simple-pdf-to-text-conversion/

Then, once you have the PDF to text conversion, you can read HDFS input from Spark.

Goto http://spark.apache.org/examples.html and look for Word Count example.  There are examples in Scala, Python, Java.  The examples even show how you can specify a HDFS location, but you can use a local filesystem as well.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The SparkContext has a method called hadoopFile. You need to rewrite FileInputFormat, same as [how to read image using spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015641/how-to-use-hadoop-inputformats-in-apache-spark) . 
And also read [Pdf Input Format implementation for Hadoop Mapreduce](https://amalgjose.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/pdf-input-format-implementation-for-hadoop-mapreduce/)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Link-only answers are discouraged. Could you please include the essential parts of your links within your answer.